# Unity2D Disable player movement for X seconds

Tags: unity-game-engine, timer, disabled-input

I am trying to disable a player movement for 1 second when it collides with a specific object.  The object collides and it detects that just fine however currently the entire game freezes and does not return.

Ive implemented a 0 value (as found in other examples) to the X and Y movements with a timer.  This freezes the game entirely and I have to kill process and reopen Unity.

```
public Boolean frozen = false;
    float shipDisabledTimer = 1f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        SetUpMoveBoundaries();
        gameSession = FindObjectOfType<GameSession>();

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        Move(frozen);
        Fire();

        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene() == SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Game"))
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))

                SceneManager.LoadScene("Game Over");
        }
    }



    public void Move(Boolean Frozen)
    {

        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Update1 - " + Frozen);



            var deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
            var deltaY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;

            var newXPos = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x + deltaX, xMin, xMax);
            var newYPos = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y + deltaY, yMin, yMax);
            transform.position = new Vector2(newXPos, newYPos);

        if (frozen == true)
        {
            float timer = 0f;
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(frozen);
            while (timer < shipDisabledTimer)
            {
                newXPos = 0;
                newYPos = 0;

            }
            disableship(frozen = false);

        }

    }


    public Boolean disableship(Boolean frozen)
    {
        return frozen;
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(other.gameObject.name);
        if (other.gameObject.name.Equals("Orb Shot(Clone)"))
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Orb hit player");
            //StartCoroutine(countdownTimer());
            disableship(frozen = true);
        }
    }
```

The ship alone should freeze.  No other game object should freeze.  All scores, counters, enemies should continue onward. Only the player X,Y are disabled for 1 second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```c#
while (timer < shipDisabledTimer)
{
    newXPos = 0;
    newYPos = 0;
}
```

entirely blocks your game's main thread since the `timer` nor `shipDisabledTime` are not changed within the loop so it will never end.

There are a few ways you could go here.

#### Invoke

[`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) allows you to call a method after a certain delay so you could easily do something like

```c#
public void Freeze()
{
    frozen = true;
    Invoke("Unfreeze"; shipDisabledTime);
}

private void Unfreeze()
{
    frozen = false;
}
```

#### Coroutine

A [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) is like a temporary `Update` method. Simplest way in your case is using [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) and do something like

```c#
public void Freeze()
{
    StartCoroutine (FreezeRoutine());
}

private IEnumerator FreezeRoutine()
{
    frozen = true;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(shipDisabledTime);

    frozen = false;
}
```

#### simple timer

Or you could use a simple timer but in `Update` (not a while loop) like

```c#
private float timer = -1;

public void Freeze()
{
    frozen = true;
    timer = shipDisabledTime;
}

private void Update()
{
    if(timer > 0)
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(timer <= 0)
        {
            timer = -1;
            frozen = false;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

---

And then either way you simply don't take any movement input in the meantime

```c#
public void Move()
{
    if(frozen) return;

    ...
}
```

---

Except for the `Invoke` solution you can also extend them and decided whether you want to e.g. stack multiple freezes, ignore them while already frozen or simply start the timers over.

---

General note: In c# rather simply use `bool` it's basically the same but easier to read and write ;)

---

Also note that this call

```c#
disableship(frozen = false);

...

public Boolean disableship(Boolean frozen)
{
    return frozen;
}
```

Is pretty strange ... first of all this method does absolutely nothing than just return the same value you pass in as parameter .. you are *hiding* the `frozen` field with a same named parameter so this does nothing!

Second your method returns a `Boolean` but you are not assigning it to anything.

If you want to change the value simply set it using `frozen = XY` but don't pass this in as parameter further.

---

Aaand avoid calling `Debug.Log` every frame .. it will slow down your app even in a build where you don't even see the log!

Comment: I used the Coroutine.  That worked perfectly.  Thank you